# Change URL Path Parameter in Angular 2 Without Changing Active Route

Tags: angular, url-routing

I'm trying to figure out a way to update a path parameter in my URL without changing the currently active route. For example, say I have the following routes:

```
{
    path: 'pages/:pageId',
    component: PageComponent,
    children: [
    {
        path: 'sections/:sectionId',
        component: PageSectionComponent,
        children: [
        {
            path: 'details',
            component: PageSectionDetailsComponent
        }]
    }]
}
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is, when somebody changes the `:pageId`, I want to keep their active route while changing the URL. So if they change `:pageId` from 999 to 777, their route should change from:

```
pages/999/sections/123/details   =>   pages/777/sections/123/details
pages/999/sections/123           =>   pages/777/sections/123
```

Additionally, I need to make this work for `:sectionId`. For example, navigating from `:sectionId` 123 to 456:

```
pages/999/sections/123/details   =>   pages/999/sections/456/details
pages/999/sections/123           =>   pages/999/sections/456
```

There are several child routes in my project that I omitted, so absolute links would be very difficult to maintain. I'm hoping I can somehow use the current `ActivatedRoute`, change the single parameter I'm updating, then navigate to that route using the `Router`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Additional info:

*I'm using Angular 4.0.0*

*There's a similar question that gets at the core problem I'm trying to solve, but it's out of date: [Change a single route parameter on the current route in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084169/change-a-single-route-parameter-on-the-current-route-in-angular-2)*

Answer (score 3):

You can update to the new required parameter in code or in the HTML ... whichever makes most sense in your application.

In the HTML, you'd do it with a routerLink directive:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/products', product.id]">{{product.productName}}</a>
```

Or with code like this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/products', this.product.id]);
```

Or with your example:

```
this.router.navigate(['/pages', this.pageId, '/sections', this.sectionId]);
```

(I think I misunderstood the question the first time.)

Comment: I don't think this will work across all of my child routes. For example, if I do `this.router.navigate(['/pages', pageId, '/sections', sectionId])`, then `/pages/999/sections/123/details` will go to `/pages/777/sections/123` instead of `/pages/777/sections/123/details`. The problem I'm having is how to keep the *entire* active route, without hardcoding my location changes.

Comment: How are the routes activated? Is it possible to post your code somewhere or provide a plunker?

Comment: You could also consider using query parameters instead of required parameters. That would mean removing the Ids from the route configuration and just passing it as a set of query parameters that is an object with the two ids.

Comment: Something like this: `pages/sections/details?page=999&section=123`

Comment: Then you can just update the query parameters without affecting the main route path.